# How to find out oldest file from a directory??? (PHP)

Tags: php, filemtime

I have a directory named 'backup'

its contains following files (with some specific details)

```
No---File Name----------------------------------------------------------------Date--------------------Time-----------Size

1.  blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-22-18AM.zip  11-April-2012   08:22:18AM  5.28MB
2.  blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-25-24AM.zip  11-April-2012   08:25:25AM  5.28MB
3.  blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-25-46AM.zip  11-April-2012   08:25:47AM  5.28MB
4.  blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-26-07AM.zip  11-April-2012   08:26:08AM  5.28MB
5.  blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-27-52AM.zip  11-April-2012   08:27:53AM  5.28MB
```

I want to get oldest file from 'backup' directory
Like 'blog-backup_on_11-April-2012_at_08-22-18AM.zip' its the oldest file in directory.

I tried [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) but unable to handle logic.

Please give some suggestion, how to get this file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785039/php-find-oldest-file-in-a-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dir = 'path/to/backup/';

foreach (glob($dir.'*.zip') as $filename) {
  $time = filemtime($filename);
  $files[$time] = $filename;
}
krsort($files);

echo reset($files);
```

Comment: glob() returns the complete path including the $dir, so I think it should be filemtime($filename); without $dir, right?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $dir_path = 'c:/my_dir';
    if($handle = opendir($dir_path))
    {

        while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
        {
            $created = filemtime($dir_path . $entry);
            $myfiles[$created] = $entry;
        }



        krsort($myfiles); //first element is oldest file

        print_r($myfiles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the previous answers are mentioning `krsort();` as it actually makes the first element the *newest* file. Using

```
    ksort($file_arr);
    echo reset($file_arr);
```

will echo the oldest file. The beginning code as already mentioned doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless one can make a clear one-liner of some kind, which I do not yet see here. I prefer readable and comprehensible algorithms that do not rely on you remembering what the various sort function do.

```
$latest_file_time = 0;
foreach(glob("backup/*") as $this_filename){
        $file_changed_time = filemtime($this_filename);
        if($file_changed_time > $latest_file_time){
                $latest_file = $this_filename;
                $latest_file_time = $file_changed_time;
        }
}

echo "latest file time = $latest_file_time latest file name = $latest_file";
```